# How to add a legend to a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

I've looked through answers for plotting legends on ggplot. However, none of the methods appear to be working for my code, which is as follows:

```
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


inputManhattan <- read_xlsx("PlotsManhattan.xlsx")
PercentMN <- inputManhattan$Percent
ComNormMN <- inputManhattan$ComNorm
ElevationMN <- inputManhattan$Elevation



ggplot(inputManhattan, aes(PercentMN, ComNormMN)) +
  geom_point(shape = 22, size = ElevationMN/20, col='orange', alpha = 0.5, fill = "grey50") +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE, color = 'orange') +
  xlab("Slope") + ylab("Total Normalized Complaints")
```

I get this graph, where Slope is plotted against complaints, and the elevation is represented by the size of the square:
[Manhattan Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqb6y.png)

I want my legend to read: "Elevation = Size of Squares" or if there is an illustration I could use in my legend, that would be great.

But I just cannot even get a legend to appear. I'd appreciate any help thanks.

Some data values:
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kgvc.png)

Comment: Put `size = ElevationMN/20` inside `aes()` (keep it in the `geom_point` layer). Then you can add `labs(size = "Elevation")`

Comment: Is `theme(legend.title=element_blank())` in `ElevationMN` variable assignment an error? Have you tried removing it and making `ElevationMN <- inputManhattan$Elevation/20`  (then removing "/20" from `geom_point(...)`) instead? And use `aes(...)` as @GregorThomas suggested.

Comment: If you need more help than that, please make your question reproducible by sharing some data. `dput` is the best way to do that because it is copy/pasteable and preserves class and structure information. Something like `dput(inputManhattan[1:20, ])` for the first 20 rows (or some other suitable subset).

Comment: Thanks Gregor and LC. I tried both methods. Yet, neither seems to be producing a legend. Gregor, I added a screenshot of my data. I tried dput, but I have so many columns.

Comment: And yes, the theme(legend.title=element_blank()) was an error

Comment: Select the three columns that you need and then dput. You can do `df <- dplyr::select(inputManhattan, Percent, ComNorm, Elevation)` and then `dput(df)`.

Comment: Yeah, subset your data to include only relevant columns and only a few rows. `dput()` that subset. I can't test or demonstrate code on a screenshot of data, and I also want to make sure the sample data has the same classes and structure, which aren't apparent from the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```r
ggplot(inputManhattan, aes(Percent, ComNorm)) + 
    geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE, color = 'orange') + 
    geom_point(
        aes(size = Elevation/20), 
        shape = 22, 
        col = 'orange', 
        alpha = 0.5, 
        fill = "grey50") + 
    xlab("Slope") + 
    ylab("Total Normalized Complaints")
```

Any column names that are inside your `inputManhattan` dataset go inside the `aes()`. 
In my example code above, you don't need `PercentMN`, `ComNormMN`, and `ElevationMN`.

I ran a similar code using `mtcars` dataset and got a legend:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
    geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE, color = 'orange') + 
    geom_point(
        aes(size = wt/20), 
        shape = 22, 
        col = 'orange', 
        alpha = 0.5, 
        fill = "grey50")
```

[image: ggplot example]